# How to get attributes from object which is in another one?

Tags: mongodb

here is an example structure of one object in my MongoDB:

```
{    
 "itemClass": 4,
 "containerSlots": 0,
 "itemBind": 1,
 "weaponInfo": {
   "dps": "0.0",
   "damage": {
     "maxDamage": 0,
     "minDamage": 0
   },
   "weaponSpeed": "0.5"
 }
}
```

I need to find maxDamage which is 1

here is my query:

```
db.items.find({"maxDamage" : "1"}).limit(3)
```

but it returns nothing

p.s. there are a lot of objects with attribute maxDamage is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) like this:

```
db.items.find({"weaponInfo.damage.maxDamage": 1})
```